# Check for e-mail values before submitting

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Before submitting the form I need a function to check for `@` and `.` symbols.

Function responsible for checking that values are inserted:

```
// function ValidateAndSend
function ValidateAndSend (event:MouseEvent):void {

    // validate fields
    if(!name_txt.length) {
        status_txt.text = "Please enter your name";
    } else if (!email_txt.length) {
        status_txt.text = "Please enter your e-mail address";
    } else if (!phone_txt.length) {
        status_txt.text = "Please enter your phone number";
    } else {

        // All is good, send the data now to PHP

        // ready the variables in our form for sending
        variables.userName = name_txt.text;
        variables.userEmail = email_txt.text;       
        variables.userPhone = phone_txt.text;
        variables.userShop = shopList.value;

        // Send the data to PHP now
        varLoader.load(varSend);

    } // close else condition for error handling

} // close validate and send function
```

I've tried creating a separate function for checking the e-mail symbols:

```
// Checking e-mail
function checkEmail():Boolean {

    var reEmail:String = email_txt.text;
    var emailOk:Boolean = false;
    var checkArray1:Array = reEmail.split("@");
    if (checkArray1.length >1) {

        var checkArray2:Array = checkArray1[1].split(".");
        if (checkArray2.length >1) {

            emailOk = true;
        }
    }
    return emailOk;
}
```

but this doesn't work. How would you achieve this?

**Update:** I've tried running the function inside `ValidateAndSend` function. But now if the email address is wrong it won't send the message but it still displays a successful submitting message.

```
// function ValidateAndSend
function ValidateAndSend (event:MouseEvent):void {

// validate fields
if(!name_txt.length) {
    status_txt.text = "Please enter your name";
} else if (!email_txt.length) {
    status_txt.text = "Please enter your e-mail";

    // Checking e-mail
    function checkEmail():Boolean {

    var reEmail:String = email_txt.text;
    var emailOk:Boolean = false;
    var checkArray1:Array = reEmail.split("@");
    if (checkArray1.length >1) {

        status_txt.text = "Please check your e-mail address";

        var checkArray2:Array = checkArray1[1].split(".");
        if (checkArray2.length >1) {

            emailOk = true;
        }
    }
    return emailOk;
    }

} else if (!phone_txt.length) {
    status_txt.text = "Please enter your phone number";
} else {

    // All is good, send the data now to PHP

    // ready the variables in our form for sending
    variables.userName = name_txt.text;
    variables.userEmail = email_txt.text;       
    variables.userPhone = phone_txt.text;
    variables.userShop = shopList.value;

    // Send the data to PHP now
    varLoader.load(varSend);

} // close else condition for error handling

} // close validate and send function
```

Comment: The function for checking emails seems OK, but did you call for it in `ValidateAndSend()`?

Comment: No, just as a separate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use regular expressions for this.

Your checkEmail() function won't be needed

```
// function ValidateAndSend
function ValidateAndSend (event:MouseEvent):void {
    var emailCheckRegExp:RegExp = /^[\w.-]+@\w[\w.-]+\.[\w.-]*[a-z][a-z]$/i;
    // validate fields
    if(name_txt.length == 0) {
        status_txt.text = "Please enter your name";
    } 
    else if (email_txt.length == 0) {
        status_txt.text = "Please enter your e-mail address";
    } 
    else if (phone_txt.length == 0) {
        status_txt.text = "Please enter your phone number";
    }
    else if(emailCheckRegExp.exec(email_txt.text) == null)
    {
        status_txt.text = "Entered e-mail is not valid";
    }
    else {

        // All is good, send the data now to PHP

        // ready the variables in our form for sending
        variables.userName = name_txt.text;
        variables.userEmail = email_txt.text;       
        variables.userPhone = phone_txt.text;
        variables.userShop = shopList.value;

        // Send the data to PHP now
        varLoader.load(varSend);

    } // close else condition for error handling

} // close validate and send function
```

Comment: I'm getting `Implicit coercion of a value of type fl.controls:TextInput to an unrelated type String.` error.

Comment: omg, sorry, forgot to add .text property of your text field) Updated now, check it out

Comment: Yes, works as it should. Many thanks for your help KumoKairo! +1 Up vote coming your way.